# Array of structures in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, struct

I need a way to implement the following C++ in javascript.

```
struct login
{
   char username[14];
   char password[7];
   char verificationCode[11];
   int timesLoged;
}; 

login allLogins[] = 
{
      {"none", "", "",0},
      {"user1", "159951", "",0},
      {"user2", "123321", "",0},
      {"user3", "456654", "",0}
};
```

I would like to be able to refer to each member in similar/same fashion.

```
String currentLoginName = allLogins[3].username
```

Comment: Uhh, this isn't JavaScript.

Comment: nop, its in C++ and wont run in Javascript

Comment: Please try something before asking.

Comment: @Vangde if you can do this in C++ it's almost impossible not to be able to figure out how to do it in JavaScript.

Comment: Read this first: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: Unfortunately C++ and javascript both are very different languages and share almost no advanced features. This will be possible to do in javascript as same because javascript is not compiled like C++.. . this kind of code is complied by compiler and converted to something straight code like what can be done in javascript as well.

Comment: Well the tho languages differ quite a lot in syntax and im not very familiar with javascript.
For exampe i found out that there is no structs in Js.

Comment: Read about classes in Javascript and if you still find problem, here is the solution: https://jsfiddle.net/ayvgnv0r/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code by  Rahul Jain.

```
class Login {
  constructor(username, password, verificationCode, timesLoged) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.verificationCode = verificationCode;
    this.timesLoged = timesLoged;
  }
}

var allLogins = [
    new Login("none", "", "",0),
  new Login("user1", "159951", "",0),
  new Login("user2", "123321", "",0),
  new Login("user3", "456654", "",0)
]

alert(allLogins[3].password);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function User([username,password,verification,times]){
  return {
   username,
   password,
   verification,
   times
  };
}

const allLogins = [
 ["user","test","1234",0],
 ["user2", "test2","1235", 0]
].map(User);
```

One could map a 2d array to an array of Users.